# Can Kakashi use the jutsu he copied without the Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

I'm not talking about Sharingan specific moves like Amaterasu, but the ones he had copied with the Sharingan like Water Dragon Jutsu.

With the sharingan he has copied and can use over a thousand moves.  Lets say he no longer has it (removed), does he retain the skills he had copied?

Does it depend on Sharingan or the skill of the user?

Comment: your question is unclear. The title says "without" while the body of the question says "with". Could you please modify the title and/body to make things a little more clear.

Comment: Well the body states the techniques he had copied while he had the sharingan.  But lets say he no longer has it (it was removed).  Does he retain the skills he had copied?

Comment: please add that to your question

Comment: To clarify he is called copy ninja because he had copied over a 1000 jutsu's and can use them in battle.  But he always had sharingan when he used his copied skills. Basically does sharingan retain the skills learned or does kakashi?

Comment: he more then likely would retain the jutsu's he had learned and would be able to use them. but wouldn't be able to copy new ones.

Comment: Good question. I've always assumed he can use them without Sharingan activated. The Sharingan just feeds the information into his brain, but then once he understands the jutsu it should be the same as using any other jutsu he knows.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question you there. Kakashi uses the Sharingan to copy ninjutsu that he has seen from other ninjas like the Water Dragon Jutsu and to continue using them, he has used his memory and experience to remember the seals to perform them. The Sharingan is a tool which he uses it to learn other ninja's ninjutsu the fast way and his brain memorises the ninjutsu so that he can cast it instantly whenever he needs it.

Hope I have answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed a good question.

Yes, but there is a limit. Based on the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sharingan):

> *The Sharingan's second-most prominent ability grants the user an incredible clarity of perception. This allows the user to pick up on subtle details, enabling them to read lip movements or mimic something like pencil movements.*

Now, if a Sharingan user has this *incredible clarity of perception*, he can easily copy hand seals. The result is that he can copy that jutsu and store that in his memory for other use. On the other hand, since it is a *copied jutsu*, it doesn't mean that he *master* that jutsu. As a result, Kakashi requires more chakra to perform that jutsu thus giving him a limitation to use them frequently.

In addition, he can't fully utilize/copy if a jutsu requires [Kekkei genkai](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kekkei_Genkai) (not just hand seals).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bryan Se To  above.

In terms of copying, I see the Sharingan as a camera. 
It takes crystal clear images of the jutsu being perform from hand seals to chakra.
Kakashi remembers these images and can perform the same jutsu providing he have the same type of chakra and able to perform the hand seals.
He probably have images of jutsu he can't perform like bloodline limits, but still have knowledge of it.

With the sharingan like a camera, so long as he have the mental images in his brain he can perform the jutsu even if the sharingan is destroy/removed.
Kind of like taking photos of your girlfriend. Doesn't matter if she destroy the camera, you still have the photos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes he can. His sharingan enables him to see the hand seals movement of the enemy, where then he do the same seals, thus copying the jutsu. However, during Naruto's training of Rasen Shuriken, he told Naruto that he can copy the Rasengan but only up to the level where the Rasengan is on the palm in its sphere form. **He cannot copy beyond that** despite the fact that Rasengan is not a Kekkei Genkai jutsu. What this means is that the Sharingan is not the reason he can copy other people's jutsu. Sharingan helped him copying jutsu by seeing the hand seals, but what enabled him to perform the jutsu is that **he has the elemental affinity for the jutsu**. So far, it has been shown that Kakashi is able to use 4 of the 5 basic elements (fire, water, earth, and lightning). His main affinity is lightning, though.

Also, based on the manga where ninjas not from Village of the Hidden Rock used earth jutsu to stop the bijuudama, it seems that up to a certain level, people can use jutsu of elements that they don't have the affinity for. But, considering that Rasengan was said to be an A rank jutsu (or S, not sure) it is possible that people's element affinity itself has its level. Meaning that Kakashi had the affinity for 4 of the 5 basic elements with lightning being the strongest considering his only original jutsu (Raikiri a.k.a Chidori) is of that element. This fits the fact of him being able to use Rasengan, an A rank jutsu, but not being able to use Rasen Shuriken, an S rank jutsu which requires elemental transformation.

Comment: Kakashi has never used a Wind based nature transformation. He can use Fire, Water, Earth and Lightning, Lightning being the one he has the natural affinity for. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Special:BrowseData/Characters?Chakra_type=Wind_Release&Media=Manga

Answer (score 0):

Well...yep he can use those jutsu which he sees with Hus sharingan....sharingan notes those hand seals which a ninja performs and Kakashi at the same time remembers them.
After remembering them it's easy for him to perform the jutsu in future however more chakra is required for him. ...
+ we may not forget that he has a affinity for lightning element...which certainly means that other jutsu which he copies....cannot be performed by their fullest potential.. However with time and experience he can perform those abilities with their required amount of chakra and less burden

Answer (score -3):

Kakashi can use wind style, too. He uses the Rasengan, which is a wind style jutsu. This is during his teaching Naruto with the wood user Yamato. So, I guess I have my answer: he can use all styles.

Comment: The [Rasengan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Rasengan) is not the same as the [Wind Release: Rasengan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Wind_Release:_Rasengan). Only the latter jutsu requires affinity for the wind element to be able to perform it.